# use hudson to get remote tests results

Tags: web-services, continuous-integration, hudson

I've a server running a proprietary language on which I'm able to run "unit tests" in this language. I cannot install a Hudson slave on this machine, but would like to have these tests results appearing in a job of hudson (to have at least a monitoring of the code quality for this server code).
I'm currently trying to use web services to get the results and store them in Hudson workspace, but I do fear it is not the right solution.
What solutions can you advice me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have gotten through the web services path, although it was not easy.
There are some steps in this path

1. I created a maven mojo with groovy (see [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Implementing+Maven+Plugins) for more infos) which, using [groovyws](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS), called a web service that, from tests results, creates the [junit report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556/spec-for-junit-xml-output/825207#825207).
2. Armed with this mojo, I created a maven project that called the web service and stores the junit.xml file in an output folder
3. Finally, i created in hudson a maven job for this project and called it regularly. Thanks to junit reporting integration in maven builds, my tests results are visible as a graph in Hudson and user can drill down to failing tests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are possible but...

Maybe one option is when the build job finished execute a second build target or script to scp the test results from the remote server to the local build server so they appear in hudson

Or if the platform allows

Map a directory on the remote machine to the local file system by using something like sshfs etc

karl

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can scp or whatever the results (in junit xml format) to the current workspace dir using a script task. Then have a "Publish JUnit test result report" post-build task & point it at the copied-in files.

Obviously if it's not in junit-compatible format you'll have to convert it.

Sounds like you're on the right path though