# producing a correct and complete xml unit testing report (for Hudson)

Tags: unit-testing, r, hudson, junit4, jenkins

I'm extending [svUnit](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/svUnit/?root=sciviews) (a unit testing suite for R, part of [sciViews](http://www.sciviews.org/SciViews-R/)) so that it produces also output that can be read by Hudson.  actually I already have something that does this, but it does not handle 'deactivated' tests.

to see what I mean, have a look at the `protocol_junit.svTestData` method in the [svTestData.R](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/svUnit/R/svTestData.R?view=markup&root=sciviews) file.

the problem is that I did not manage to find any definition of the schema accepted by Hudson and I did manage to convince a Java project to fail and error, so that its test suite would add a `<failure/>` and `<error/>` element inside of a few `<testcase/>` elements, but I did not manage to see what happens with a `@Ignore @Test` decoration.

many others have asked this same question, for example [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556), but in the end one gets to [this page](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/schema-for-junit-xml-output-td1375274.html) which is a good starting point but is not complete.  for example, it does not mention the `<error/>` element I discovered by trial and error.

I tried to read the source read by Hudson, but I did not find where to start.

any hints?

Comment: Other things to see: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3007 (updated location of bug report mentioned elsewhere); https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43969 (Ant RFE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gave a closer look at the Hudson sources (in particular, [CaseResult.java](http://fisheye.hudson-ci.org/browse/Hudson/trunk/hudson/main/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/junit/CaseResult.java)) I saw that including a `<skipped/>` element in a `<testcase/>` element is what I was looking for.

and just for future reference, the RELAX NG compact syntax of the schema I am producing (feel free to edit/maintain):

```
junit.rnc:
#----------------------------------------
start = testsuite

property = element property {
   attribute name {text},
   attribute value {text}
}

properties = element properties {
   property*
}

failure = element failure {
   attribute message {text},
   attribute type {text},
   text
}

error = element error {
   attribute message {text},
   attribute type {text},
   text
}

skipped = element skipped {
   text
}

testcase = element testcase {
   attribute classname {text},
   attribute name {text},
   attribute time {text},
   (failure|error)?,
   skipped?
}

testsuite = element testsuite {
   attribute errors {xsd:integer},
   attribute failures {xsd:integer},
   attribute hostname {text},
   attribute name {text},
   attribute tests {xsd:integer},
   attribute time {xsd:double},
   attribute timestamp {xsd:dateTime},
   properties,
   testcase*,
   element system-out {text},
   element system-err {text}
}
#----------------------------------------


and junitreport.rnc
#----------------------------------------
include "junit.rnc" {
   start = testsuites
   testsuite = element testsuite {
      attribute errors {xsd:integer},
      attribute failures {xsd:integer},
      attribute hostname {text},
      attribute name {text},
      attribute tests {xsd:integer},
      attribute time {xsd:double},
      attribute timestamp {xsd:dateTime},
      attribute id {text},
      attribute package {text},
      properties,
      testcase*,
      element system-out {text},
      element system-err {text}
   }
}

testsuites = element testsuites {
   testsuite*
}
#----------------------------------------
```