# How to use Hudson with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm trying to use Hudson as a continuous integration system to manage a php project (cakePHP).
It's using simpleTest tests.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791979/how-do-you-run-simpletest-from-hudson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://jenkins-php.org/.