# Does the JUnit XML format really not have an error element?

Tags: java, ant, junit

Looking at the [informal spec](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/schema-for-junit-xml-output-td1375274.html) at from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports), I notice that there is no element for errors. Is that just an oversight? CruiseControl seems to extract errors from somewhere.

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="name" errors="1" failures="0">
    <testcase name="name">
      <error>Some error message</error>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view this [article](http://ideoplex.com/id/41/ant-and-multiple-junit-test-cases). The modified sample from this article:

```
<target name="test">
    <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" fork="off" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
        <test name="packagename.MyTest"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

You can see all messages from junit tests in console (or in report file)
You can read about `printsummary, haltonfailure` properties and the other ones at the [ant site](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).
The other [useful link](http://pub.admc.com/howtos/junit4x/ant-chapt.html).

Comment: I'm not using Ant but rather creating a script which tries to be compatible (CI tools) and so just need to know how the standard handles errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but, there is an element for errors, and you can distinguish between errors and failures:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites errors="1" failures="2" tests="5" time="10">
    <testsuite errors="1" failures="2" id="0" name="TestSuite1" tests="4" timestamp="2015-04-20T00:00:00">
        <testcase classname="ModuleIAmTesting" name="testDoNothingDoesNothing" time="1"/>
        <testcase classname="ModuleIAmTesting" name="testLongThingTakesALongTime" time="5"/>

        <testcase classname="ModuleIAmTesting" name="testSkyIsBlue" time="1">
            <failure message="Test testSkyIsBlue() failed!" type="failure">
                It's storming; sky is gray today. Failure output, details, etc.
            </failure>
        </testcase>

        <testcase classname="ModuleIAmTesting" name="testIsNotStorming" time="1">
            <failure message="Test testIsNotStorming() failed!" type="failure">
                Another failure. Failure output, details, etc.
            </failure>
        </testcase>

        <testcase classname="ModuleIAmTesting" name="testCreatePlugin" time="2">
            <error message="Error while executing test testCreatePlugin()!" type="error">
                Unhandled catastrophic exception in ModuleIAmTesting.cpp at like 4420, details, etc.
            </error>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

The important part is the `<error>` tag and the `errors` attribute to `<testsuite>`.