# Creating a standard test report file from custom test scripts/code

Tags: java, ant, hudson, integration-testing

For an integration test setup, we have written some custom scripts and code to run tests based on the results of from the different external system and changing able configurations on out internal system.

What We would like to do is report these test, from within our build environment, Hudson. I don’t particular want to write a custom Hudson plug-in with a custom report format, and was hoping to retro-fit a standard xml report format like JUnit and let Hudson do the fancy reporting.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the minimum xml report requirements for any of the standard unit testing report formats that Hudson accepts?

Currently the scripts are executed via ANT, and the code added as Ant Tasks, being that once the system has been started and all external parts are attached and checked, a list of tests that can be run and changed based on properties within ANT and the env/server it is on.

Comment: I think you already hinted at it.... use the JUnit XML output format.  This might help [Stack Overflow: Junit XML Format Hudson Supports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output a report in the Standard Test Report format something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="Suite of Tests" package="com.test.reporting" tests="2" time="125" timestamp="2012-04-24T03:03:38">
    <testcase name="Test2" time="0"/>
    <testcase name="Test1" time="0"/>
</testsuite>
```

requires some custom code... but pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [code.google.com/p/shell2junit](http://code.google.com/p/shell2junit) as referenced in [JUnit XML Format Specification that Hudson supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports/)