# Python unittests in Jenkins?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, xunit

How do you get Jenkins to execute python unittest cases?
Is it possible to JUnit style XML output from the builtin `unittest` package?

Comment: All of the answers presume you want to initiate the test cases from the command-line. But if you want to run the tests programmatically, try this: `import nose ; nose.runmodule()  # aka  nose.run(defaultTest=__name__)`

Comment: IMHO the simple 'py.test --junitxml results.xml test.py' suggestion answers the question best. 'yum install pytest' to get py.test installed. Then you can run any unittest python script and get jUnit xml results

Comment: @gaoithe that answers the jenkins part, but doesn't fulfill the requirement to use the builtin unittest module. In that project it was a given requirement.

Comment: @erikb85 When I say "run any unittest python script" I mean a script which uses the unittest module.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

## sample tests:

tests.py:

```
# tests.py

import random
try:
    import unittest2 as unittest
except ImportError:
    import unittest

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skip("demonstrating skipping")
    def test_skipped(self):
        self.fail("shouldn't happen")

    def test_pass(self):
        self.assertEqual(10, 7 + 3)

    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(11, 7 + 3)
```

## [JUnit with pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files)

run the tests with:

```
py.test --junitxml results.xml tests.py
```

results.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" name="pytest" skips="1" tests="2" time="0.097">
    <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_fail" time="0.000301837921143">
        <failure message="test failure">self = &lt;tests.SimpleTest testMethod=test_fail&gt;

    def test_fail(self):
&gt;       self.assertEqual(11, 7 + 3)
E       AssertionError: 11 != 10

tests.py:16: AssertionError</failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_pass" time="0.000109910964966"/>
    <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_skipped" time="0.000164031982422">
        <skipped message="demonstrating skipping" type="pytest.skip">/home/damien/test-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/_pytest/unittest.py:119: Skipped: demonstrating skipping</skipped>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

## [JUnit with nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html)

run the tests with:

```
nosetests --with-xunit
```

nosetests.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="nosetests" tests="3" errors="0" failures="1" skip="1">
    <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_fail" time="0.000">
        <failure type="exceptions.AssertionError" message="11 != 10">
            <![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2-0.5.1-py2.6.egg/unittest2/case.py", line 340, in run
testMethod()
File "/home/damien/tests.py", line 16, in test_fail
self.assertEqual(11, 7 + 3)
File "/opt/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2-0.5.1-py2.6.egg/unittest2/case.py", line 521, in assertEqual
assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
File "/opt/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2-0.5.1-py2.6.egg/unittest2/case.py", line 514, in _baseAssertEqual
raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 11 != 10
]]>
        </failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_pass" time="0.000"></testcase>
    <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_skipped" time="0.000">
        <skipped type="nose.plugins.skip.SkipTest" message="demonstrating skipping">
            <![CDATA[SkipTest: demonstrating skipping
]]>
        </skipped>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

## [JUnit with nose2](http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/junitxml.html)

You would need to use the `nose2.plugins.junitxml` plugin. You can configure `nose2` with a config file like you would normally do, or with the `--plugin` command-line option.

run the tests with:

```
nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml --junit-xml tests
```

nose2-junit.xml:

```
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" name="nose2-junit" skips="1" tests="3" time="0.001">
  <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_fail" time="0.000126">
    <failure message="test failure">Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damien/Work/test2/tests.py", line 18, in test_fail
    self.assertEqual(11, 7 + 3)
AssertionError: 11 != 10
</failure>
  </testcase>
  <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_pass" time="0.000095" />
  <testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_skipped" time="0.000058">
    <skipped />
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

## [JUnit with unittest-xml-reporting](https://github.com/danielfm/unittest-xml-reporting)

Append the following to `tests.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import xmlrunner
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))
```

run the tests with:

```
python tests.py
```

test-reports/TEST-SimpleTest-20131001140629.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="0" name="SimpleTest-20131001140629" tests="3" time="0.000">
    <testcase classname="SimpleTest" name="test_pass" time="0.000"/>
    <testcase classname="SimpleTest" name="test_fail" time="0.000">
        <error message="11 != 10" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 16, in test_fail
    self.assertEqual(11, 7 + 3)
AssertionError: 11 != 10
]]>     </error>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="SimpleTest" name="test_skipped" time="0.000">
        <skipped message="demonstrating skipping" type="skip"/>
    </testcase>
    <system-out>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-out>
    <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-err>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: +1 for the simple 'py.test --junitxml results.xml test.py' suggestion. 'yum install pytest' to get py.test installed. Then you can run any unittest python script and get jUnit xml results.

Comment: If you want to use _unittest-xml-reporting_ and benefit from the [Test Discovery feature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery), you can put `unittest.main(module=None, testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))`.

Comment: @RosbergLinhares why do you need `module=None` to use Test Discovery? It works exactly as described in the answer `unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))`.

Comment: @RosbergLinhares, during test discovery, the modules are only imported but not executed. So, how is any of those solution supposed to work with discovery? I just tried it out, none of it works. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Konstantin, I also had to include module=None for it to run correctly.

Comment: Even for me adding module=None is not working . It is still not able to discover tests am I missing something?

Answer (score 20):

I would second using nose.  Basic XML reporting is now built in.  Just use the --with-xunit command line option and it will produce a nosetests.xml file.  For example:

> nosetests --with-xunit

Then add a "Publish JUnit test result report" post build action, and fill in the "Test report XMLs" field with nosetests.xml (assuming that you ran nosetests in $WORKSPACE).

Answer (score 12):

You can install the [unittest-xml-reporting](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest-xml-reporting) package to add a test runner that generates XML to the built-in `unittest`.

We use [pytest](http://pytest.org/), which has XML output built in (it's a command line option).

Either way, executing the unit tests can be done by running a shell command.

Answer (score 7):

```
python -m pytest --junit-xml=pytest_unit.xml source_directory/test/unit || true # tests may fail
```

Run this as shell from jenkins , you can get the report in pytest_unit.xml as artifact.

Answer (score 4):

I used nosetests. There are addons to output the XML for Jenkins

Answer (score 3):

When using buildout we use [`collective.xmltestreport`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.xmltestreport) to produce JUnit-style XML output, perhaps it's [source code](https://github.com/collective/collective.xmltestreport) or the module itself could be of help.