# How to integrate pycharm with jenkins?

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, pycharm

I want to run my test suite from pycharm to run automatically whenever new build is released . We are using jenkins for CI. I want to integrate pycharm with jenkins but not sure how to do it.

Comment: something like this? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/6110-jenkins-control-plugin

Answer (score 0):

What kind of test suite do you have? What kind of version control are you using? Where are you hosting your code?

PyCharm's Jenkins plugin will show you the status of your builds. But you'll still need to configure Jenkins to run your test suite. (There's a tutorial for setting up Jenkins for Python testing here: http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/jenkins-and-python.html)

Comment: What kind of test suite do you have? - regression test suite (I am not quite clear about this question)                                                                                     What kind of version control are you using? -Github                                                  Where are you hosting your code? -pycharm code is on my local machine.  Thanks for sharing tutorial.

Comment: @Priyank the tutorial works with GitHub, so that should help you to get going. The tutorial uses nose tests, if you're using unittest, pytest, or another framework there may be some small differences. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241781/python-unittests-in-jenkins