# Is there a tool to convert Rational Functional Tester (RFT) log files to JUnit xml log format?

Tags: xml, logging, junit, hudson, rft

I want to convert my IBM Rational Functional Tester (RFT) log files to the XML format of JUnit. What's the best way to do it? Is there a tool that already does it?

Here is the [JUnit format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports). RFT can output its logs in html, xml, text and TPTP (an IBM internal format). I couldn't find a specification for it.

I plan to integrate the tool with Hudson continuous integration server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to transform HTML RFT report into JUnit XML format via XSLT.

Or you can just try a [plugin that allows to publish HTML reports](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)