# Writing test result xml file to be read by Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline

My program uses a custom testing framework but saves test results to an XML file following JUnit XML formatting as described here: [JUnit XML format specification that Hudson supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports). Jenkins is able to parse the file as expected, using the xunit plugin, and to display informative test results. However, it only sees the file when I do a manual build and a git add/commit of the test results file. What do I need to do so that Jenkins will "see" a result file that is created during the execution of the pipeline?

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'xcodebuild -scheme UnitTestRunner -configuration debug'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'xcodebuild -scheme UnitTestRunner -configuration debug || true'
                junit '**/TestResults.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to make the test results available for other stages, or even for downloading them from other applications (e.g. a test management tool) you need to publish them as artifacts:

```
stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'xcodebuild -scheme UnitTestRunner -configuration debug || true'
                junit '**/TestResults.xml'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/TestResults.xml'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the result file is generated in your workspace. Check the workspace itself or use `archiveArtifacts` to archive all files. Then you just need to define the correct pattern for the file. Be sure that you have the result file in the same `node` or `stash` it to publish in another node later.