# Jenkins support for csv test result file

Tags: jenkins

I have a test result file that looks like this:

```
test1,PASS
test2,FAIL
test3,SKIP
```

It is easy for me to vary the format as long as it remains .csv or some other simple text file.

What is an easy way to get Jenkins to recognize either natively or with commonly used plugins?

I could create a JUnit style output if I could get the minimally functional JUnit file that Jenkins would read, but I would rather not have to deal with verbose XML file for such simple test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of least resistance--like you're guessing--is junit xml format.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925847/6090676 includes a seven-line junit xml example.

Comment: That is definitely a minimal XML file.   I can work with that. It is interesting that the default is that the test is successful.