# What is the difference between 'disabled' and 'skipped' in Junit4?

Tags: testing, junit, xsd, junit4

I'm trying to build a number of test runners that share a common output format.  I'd like to adopt JUnit4 as the output standard, and found several XSDs for it.  (including a well? documented version from here: [JUnit XML format specification that Hudson supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports/9410271#9410271))

All of these XSDs agree that there is BOTH a 'skipped' and 'disabled' attribute on the 'testsuite' element, but i have never seen any XML that has both these values...

I also searched the JUnit website, where they seem to conflate 'disabled' with 'ignored' (https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Ignoring-tests).

If a test explicitely marked to be ignored (e.g. @Ignore) is called 'disabled' in the output, what is 'skipped' for and when should i use it?

Comment: Other test scaffolds, such as TestNG, have a concept of test dependencies. Identifying that a test should only be run if another test passes implements a fail-quick approach. So, any tests that weren't run because of a failed dependency will be marked as "skipped".