# How do I perform custom tests in Jenkins and produce output that Jenkins, or a plugin, understands

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, junit

I have googled this. I was unable to find an answer. How do I create a custom test that creates a report that Jenkins, or a common plugin, understands. There are a few standard test harness but I would like to create a custom one. I am happy to make it create a report in a format that imitates one of the standard ones if that then allows me to collate the test results within Jenkins using an available plugin.

Example: JUnit appears popular. Could I produce a Junit style report and use the Junit plugin to analyse the results? If this was a good approach, where can I find documentation on that format?

(see also [JUnit XML format specification that Hudson supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports))

Comment: It seems a custom output format requires a custom visualization plugin. That jUnit output schema file should be in the source code of the jUnit plugin.

Comment: @domih I am surprised there is not a standard designed for custom testers. That is it's file format is very well specified and is perhaps human readable. If I imitate results from a standard test harness it would be nice if the format was simple and well documented. As standard test harnesses tend to provide tools for writing and reading the results. They tend not to provide detail and the results format.

Comment: I think you should look for something testing related instead of Jenkins. Jenkins is not a testing tool, it is an execution tool where tests can be executed.

Comment: @domih We have an application that stand alone with custom scripting including file writing capabilities. If is not java based. It would be great to create tests scripts in the custom language to produce test reports. Jenkins is currently getting sources and building the application. It would be a simple step to make it run the tests and the script produce results. It would be very difficult to integrate the unit test tool into this scenario. This is very much a system test of the release application's scripting abilities. (Unit tests would be great too but that's not this.)