# How can I get jenkins to fail a build if the tests fail, after the reports are generated?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

So I'm trying to learn more about jenkins and I developed a shell script that execute the tests for my iOS project and generates a report. I set the script to exit as soon as failures are detected (Since this is the only way I know how to get the build to fail if the tests fail).

That's the reason why the reports were not being generated. Because I exit the script as soon as the tests failed. But I'm not familiar with how to get the build to fail, without exiting prior to the generation of the reports. What can I do to circumvent this? Here's my current shells script:

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -project "Tests.xcodeproj" 
    -scheme "Testing" 
    -sdk "iphonesimulator12.2" 
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=latest,name=iPhone 7" 
    test -only-testing:"UITests/UITests" 
    -resultBundlePath TestResults | xcpretty
xchtmlreport -r TestResults
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> always() { //some code here }

section to specific stage OR pipeline. Put the report generation in that block. Refer to https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions

In freestyle project you can add Post-build action

Comment: so the shell I have written is executed in a build step. Would this go in there as well?

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using a freestyle project, so how does this affect what I'm trying to accomplish with what you suggested?

Comment: Denys refers to a *pipeline* job.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would execute all your tests and report each test case state in a result file (in my case this is in [JUnit format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/what-is-the-junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports) for Java/JavaScript). 
After all tests have run you *publish* the result file using an appropriate Jenkins plugin step (in my case [`junit`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/#-junit-%20archive%20junit-formatted%20test%20results)).

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline/Workflow Job in Jenkins using fastlane:  What I did, is I set the post block to run three different lanes depending on the the status of the build.  The post block has sublocks called success, unstable and failure.  The lanes in the post block's subblocks post a slack message with SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILED for the three possibilities (successful build and all tests pass, successful build and 1 or more tests fail, and unsuccessful build) respectively.  I use danger gem to post test result summary back to my pull request in the repository's comments.  See here --> https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post