# ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: None of the test reports contained any result

Tags: jenkins, junit, iar

I am executing IAR unit test after executing i am trying to  publish the junit reports.
Report has a valid xml format but Jenkins is not picking up the reports shows below error

> ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: None of the
>   test reports contained any result Notifying upstream projects of job
>   completion`enter code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>

<Test>


<Test>


<testsuite tests="1" name="PrjVigilohmObjectGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="PrjVigilohmObjectGroup_Metering" time="0.3d" classname="PrjVigilohmObjectGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="PrjVarianceDefinitionEntryGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="PrjVarianceDefinitionEntryGroup_" time="0.3d" classname="PrjVarianceDefinitionEntryGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="PrjVarianceDefinitionAdvancedGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="PrjVarianceDefinitionAdvancedGroup_" time="0.3d" classname="PrjVarianceDefinitionAdvancedGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="37" name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_ProductInfo" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Commissioning" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_SILVersionInfoString" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_RSVersionInfoString" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_OSVersionInfoString" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_VersionInfoDetail" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_CrcGetter" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Reserved_Float32" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Reserved_Uint32" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Reserved_Uint16" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Unused_Registers" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Trending_GetData_IFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Trending_GetNbNewValue_IFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Reset" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_OnOffCycleNumber" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_UpTime" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Logging" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_DateTime_7reg" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_NametagIFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_DateTime" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_HW_Revision" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_ProductDetails" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_DeviceIdentifier" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_FW_Version" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_ToroidTurns" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_ToroidSelection" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_AlarmDelay" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_AlarmIFL_R" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_AlarmThresholdIFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Settings" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_CounterSetting" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_CommFunctionalSafety" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_alarmStatusIFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_productStatusIFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_MeteringIFL_Equality" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_MeteringIFL" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<testcase name="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup_Metering" time="0.3d" classname="PrjCallbackDefinitionGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="mb_masterGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="mb_masterGroup_Init" time="0.3d" classname="mb_masterGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CVigilohmObjectGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CVigilohmObjectGroup_HWReset" time="0.3d" classname="CVigilohmObjectGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CSlowMeteringGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CSlowMetering_ConnectAll" time="0.3d" classname="CSlowMeteringGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CPSResetGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CPSResetGroup_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="CPSResetGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CPSModbusGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CPSModbusGroup_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="CPSModbusGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CPSMeteringGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CPSMeteringGroup_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="CPSMeteringGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CPSIOGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CPSIOGroup_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="CPSIOGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CPSGeneralSetupGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CPSGeneralSetupGroup_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="CPSGeneralSetupGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CPSAlarmingGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CPSAlarmingGroup_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="CPSAlarmingGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="28" name="ConfigurationManagerGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_get_nbTurnsConfigCh1" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getCalibrationTime" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh12" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh11" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh10" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh9" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh8" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh7" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh6" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh5" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh4" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh3" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh2" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getAlarmDelayCh1" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getNetworkFrequency" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getFilteringTime" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh12" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh11" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh10" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh9" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh8" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh7" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh6" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh5" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh4" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh3" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh2" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<testcase name="ConfigurationManager_getToroidTypeCh1" time="0.3d" classname="ConfigurationManagerGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="10" name="Comm2ndCntrlGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="Comm2ndCntrlGroup_ReadModeSelect" time="0.3d" classname="Comm2ndCntrlGroup"/>

<testcase name="Comm2ndCntrlGroup_UpgradeFirmware" time="0.3d" classname="Comm2ndCntrlGroup"/>


<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="96" name="CMeteringGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_Craw4" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_Craw3" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_Craw2" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_Craw1" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_Rraw12" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_Rraw11" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_C11" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_C10" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_C9" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_C8" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_C7" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_C6" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_R4" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_R3" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_R2" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<testcase name="CMetering_Get_R1" time="0.3d" classname="CMeteringGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="20" name="CIndusTestGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_ReadEEPROM" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_WriteEEPROM" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_SilTest" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_SetGpioInitialization" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_GetIndusTestResultOnGpios" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_GetSerialNumber" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_WriteSerialNumber" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_PerformSoftReset" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_PerformResetLogs" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_PerformFactoryReset" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_CheckFactoryResetType" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_LaunchHWTests" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_LaunchMeteringTest" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_ReadStatusInputSate" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_SetInjectionRelay" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_SetPreAlarmRelay" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_SetKeyPressed" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_GetKeysPressed" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_WriteProductVariance" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<testcase name="CIndusTestGroup_Init" time="0.3d" classname="CIndusTestGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CFastMeteringGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CFastMetering_ConnectAll" time="0.3d" classname="CFastMeteringGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="7" name="CDiagnosticsGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_pingResponse" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_SetNewAutoTestPeriod" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_ResetNextAutoTestTime" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_Get2ndCntlrUpgradeType" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_Get2ndCntlrFWVersion" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_RunTask" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<testcase name="CDiagnosticsGroup_Init" time="0.3d" classname="CDiagnosticsGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="1" name="CFwVersionTestGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="test_CFwVersion_Init_1" time="0.3d" classname="CFwVersionTestGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>


<testsuite tests="22" name="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup" hostname="localhost" failures="0" errors="0">

<properties/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run21" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run20" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run19" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run18" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run17" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run16" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run15" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run15_1" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run14" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run13" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run12" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run11" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run10" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run9" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run8" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run7" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run6" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run5" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run4" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run3" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run2" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<testcase name="test_CAlgorithimR_Run" time="0.3d" classname="CALgorithimR_IFL_SensorGroup"/>

<systemout/>

<systemerr/>

</testsuite>

</Test>
OK (234 tests, 234 ran, 275 checks, 0 ignored, 0 filtered out, d ms) 
</test>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet of how you call the plugin in the Jenkinsfile?

Comment: I am using free style project  and  Publish Junit test results plugin . XML file is  in workspace so i have specified the xml file .  XML i have validated its shows  unable to figure out whats wrong with code.

Comment: I have got the resolution in the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/what-is-the-junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports