# How to convert CSV file to JUnit format to show it in JUnit test results in Jenkins?

Tags: python, xml, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

I have a test case where the results are saved as csv file. I want to use Jenkins to show the result, and the JUnit format is suitable for me. A part of (more than 1000) results looks like this:

CSV data:

```
TCName;OverallResult
TC_LIB_001; FAIL
TC_LIB_001; FAIL
FMECA_DIA_034; FAIL
FMECA_DIA_034; PASS
```

I looked all over the and found a lot of information but still have no clear idea how to convert my CSV file into any format that works to show the results with Jenkins... I don't know what I'm missing.

Tried and tested other XML example files and it worked in Jenkins so I think I'm missing something while converting the CSV file into XML file

So I'm wondering if you guys have any idea?

Edit:

```py
Code import sys
import os
import csv
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    os._exit(1)
path=sys.argv[1] # get folder as a command line argument
os.chdir(path)
csvFiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.csv') or f.endswith('.CSV')]
for csvFile in csvFiles:
    xmlFile = csvFile[:-4] + '.xml'
    csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
    xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
    xml_Top=  open(xmlFile, 'r')
    #xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>' + "\n")
    # there must be only one top-level tag
    rn = -1
    for rl in csvFile:
        rn+=1
    xmlData.write('<testsuite tests='+'"'+str(rn)+'"'+'>' + "\n")
    print(rn)

    rowNum = 0
    for row in csvData:
        if rowNum == 0:
            tags = row
            # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
            for i in range(len(tags)):
                tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
        else:
            xmlData.write('<testcase')
            for i in range(len(tags)):
                xmlData.write('    ' + 'classname=' + '"'+ row[i].partition(";")[0] +'"'+ ' name=' +'"'+row[i].partition(";")[2] +'"  /')
                if row[i].partition(";")[2] == " FAIL":
                    xmlData.write('>        ' + ' <failure type="did not passed"> details about failure </failure>'+ "\n")
                if row[i].partition(";")[2] != " PASS" and row[i].partition(";")[2] != " FAIL" :
                    xmlData.write('        ' + ' <failure type="Fatal Error"> details about failure </failure>'+ "\n")
                if row[i].partition(";")[2] == " PASS":
                    xmlData.write('>'+ "\n")

        rowNum +=1
    xmlData.write('</testsuite>' + "\n")
    xmlData.close()
```

Results(xml file):

```
<testsuite tests="4">
<testcase    classname="TC_LIB_001" name=" FAIL"  />         <failure type="did not passed"> details about failure </failure>
<testcase    classname="TC_LIB_001" name=" FAIL"  />         <failure type="did not passed"> details about failure </failure>
<testcase    classname="FMECA_DIA_034" name=" FAIL"  />         <failure type="did not passed"> details about failure </failure>
<testcase    classname="FMECA_DIA_034" name=" PASS"  />
</testsuite>
```

i was using the simple format from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925847

Problem: Jenkins returns the test results as passed for the 4 test cases even though I have only 1 passed case and 3 failed

Edit 2: okay solved. my idea was a first solution that shows results in Jenkins. the solution is clearly in need of improvement, depending on requirements.

/> should be closed at the end in case of failure otherwise the failure would be ignored that means that the first 3 lines... hopefully it helps someone in the future :) for more information see https://stackoverflow.com/users/34148/anders-lindahl

Comment: We have no idea what you're doing wrong because you haven't posted any code...

Comment: share the code, share the data formats,etc.