# About Jenkins JUnit XML Format

Tags: xml, junit, jenkins

I'm working on a script that generates test results in JUnit XML format that Jenkins accepts.

I read through some answers in StackOverFlow about this topic: [JUnit XML format specification that Hudson supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports)
and [Spec. for JUnit XML Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556/spec-for-junit-xml-output) but none of these talks about the detail of the "testsuites" attributes or options.

I want to show the total number of "testcase", total number of failed "testcase" and total number of skipped "testcase" from all the "testsuite" under the "testsuites".

ie `<testsuites *something to add here to include the info demanded*>...</testsuites>`

Is there a way to achieve that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think that information will be automatically computed by Jenkins. If not - don't bother adding it, it won't be displayed anyway.

Here's a useful tip on how to debug this sort of thing: create a job (let's name it *jUnitReport*) that "touches" a file (let's call it *jUnit.xml*) in a shell/batch build step; add 'Publish JUnit test resul report' and specify *jUnit.xml* in 'Test report XMLs' edit box. Run the job once - that will create its workspace. Now place valid *jUnit.xml* that you want to test in the workspace. Run the job again and examine how test results look.

It is important not to remove the 'touch' step - otherwise Jenkins will think of the test results as stale and fail the build.

You can now play with *jUnit.xml* without running actual tests and examine how it affects results Jenkins displays.

Comment: Let's say I have a new attribute in my XML file, like "total_heap_size_allocated", will this affect how Jenkins parses the existing JUnit XML file? Or will it break?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in python. So I can tell you in python.
import a package called xmlrunner

```
import xmlrunner

class ABC(unittest.TestCase)
asserts/tests..
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ABC)
   xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Now in your jenkins machine go to Post-build Actions
Click on the check box next to Publish JUnit test result report
and provide the path name to the xml file. (**/test.xml)

you should save-build and the check your detailed results.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found what you are looking for. But the following sample works for me.

```
<testsuites tests="38" failures="2" disabled="0" errors="0" time="10.898" name="AllTests">
    <!-- Add test suite and other stuff here-->
</testsuites>
```

Here is what Jenkins supports. Not sure if it is the same for Hudson.
https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/trunk/hudson/dtkit/dtkit-format/dtkit-junit-model/src/main/resources/com/thalesgroup/dtkit/junit/model/xsd/junit-4.xsd

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the similar things, and mostly it is not possible to use default junit plugin, it doesn't parse this information

You can check the source code https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/junit/SuiteResult.java#L125 for this plugin.

You can fork the junit plugin and extend it.