# How to format JUnit console output?

Tags: java, junit

Is it possible to format the JUnit output on the console in order to have a customed output?
For example the standard JUnit output from my actual tests is:

```
junits:
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_1
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_1
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 10,016 sec
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 10,016 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: insert took 3,984 sec
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_2
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_2
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 13,35 sec
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 13,35 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: load took 3,239 sec
[junit] Testcase: insert took 2,21 sec
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_3
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_3
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 12,786 sec
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 12,786 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: insert took 2,607 sec
[junit] Testcase: update took 2,338 sec
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_4
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_4
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 14,803 sec
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 14,803 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: getAll took 4,73 sec
[junit] Testcase: insert took 2,289 sec
```

I would like to better highlight each JUnit class. At least by adding some new lines in order to generate a similar output:

```
junits:
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_1
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_1
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 10,016 sec
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 10,016 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: insert took 3,984 sec
[junit]
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_2
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_2
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 13,35 sec
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 13,35 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: load took 3,239 sec
[junit] Testcase: insert took 2,21 sec
[junit]
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_3
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_3
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 12,786 sec
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 12,786 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: insert took 2,607 sec
[junit] Testcase: update took 2,338 sec
[junit]
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Running com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_4
[junit] Testsuite: com.myapp.tests.dao.Test_4
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 14,803 sec
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 14,803 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: getAll took 4,73 sec
[junit] Testcase: insert took 2,289 sec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to format the console output of JUnit. However you can have JUnit produce reports in various formats, for example [HTML](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/03/26/generating-junit-test-results-as-html-report/), or [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556/spec-for-junit-xml-output).

Also, there is a whole lot of tools out there to process the results and present them to you in a useful manner. The [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/), for example, comes packed with functions to run or debug unit tests and view the results in a tree view.

You can also use a Continous Integration System such as Jenkins to run your tests. It produces an interactive HTML report of your test results if you configure it to do so.

Comment: You're right, it will be better to process the results. As a Jenkins server is used, I will look for a documentation on how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control, you can implement your own test runner quite easily.

Derive from [`RunListener`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) – a class that handles `testStarted`, `testFinished`, `testFailure` etc – and then pass an instance of it as via `addListener()` to the [`JUnitCore`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html).

I did this once to write what I then considered a fancy console log in just a few pages of code.  It is not hard but given that you mostly want to insert a few additional line breaks, it might be a bit overkill.